# sequelize CreateAssociation return parent instance instead of child created instance

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an issue with CreateAssociation method.

Here's my code :

User create curves

```
//User create curves
function saveCurves(user, functions){
   var curves = JSON.parse(functions);

   for (var i = 0; i < curves.length; i++) {
       (function(i,user,curves){
          user.createCurve({
            i_min: curves[i].i_min,
            i_max: curves[i].i_max,
        }).then(function(curve){
            saveFunction(curve,curves[i].fn,curves[i].variables);
        });
    })(i,user,curves);

   }
}


 //save function after creating curves depends on it 
function saveFunction(curve,fct,variables){
return curve.createFunction({
    fn: fct
}).then(function(math_function){
    saveVariables(math_function,variables);
    return;
})
}


//save variables to associated function
function saveVariables(fn, variables){
for(var j= 0; j < variables.length; j++){

    (function(j,fn,variables){
        fn.createVariable({
            name: variables[j].name,
            function_id: fn.id
        })
        .then(function(row_variable){
            console.log(row_variable.toJSON())
            return row_variable.createFunction({
                fn: variables[j].fn
            })
    })(j,fn,variables);

}
```

I have an issue when I'm calling "fn.createVariable" Method. 
I don't really understand why but the promise in .then just after give me fn instance instead of variable instance.

and also I have this error : 
*Unhandled rejection TypeError: row_variable.createFunction is not a function*

When i'm looked into my database, I saw the instance has been correctly inserted
but row_variable in console.log give me fn and not inserted row.

So I cannot understand with I have this return.
I did it well above, so why it doesn't work here ?

(Not relation definition issue because row exist in database)

Any idea please ?